# How to make and bind data to a gridview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, binding, webforms

I am fairly novice to ASP.NET Web Forms and GridViews. I'm trying to create a test page with a few columns. The GridView is potentially go to allow the user to edit, delete, update or add a row. I'm not sure how to correctly bind the data table to the GridView. Do I need to bind data for it to even show up? Or can it start up with blank entries if no data binding is created? When I run my application I get a blank page with no grid.

Here is an example (there is actually more than one column, just didn't add them for brevity):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridMerit" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                ShowFooter="true"
                DataKeyNames="MeritId">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Faculty Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtFacultyName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FacultyName") %>'/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFacultyName" runat="server" width="40px" Text='<%#Eval("FacultyName") %>'/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="inFacultyName" width="140px" runat="server"/
                </Columns>
```

Comment: "Do I need to bind data for it to even show up?" Yes.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to correctly bind the data table to the GridView." `gridMerit.DataSource = mydatatable; gridMerit.DataBind();`.

Comment: You can create an `DataTable` and Add an empty row. Then bind this `DataTable` to `Gridview` in order to show an empty `GridView`.

Comment: this is not the place to start learn all that stuff - I suggest to view some tutorial and read some books - follow some steps as shown on examples.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it looks like it's running now, but the grid does not show up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample. Also you can get data from db and show in the grid.

```
    DataTable table1 = new DataTable("Faculty");
    table1.Columns.Add("name");
    table1.Columns.Add("id");
    table1.Rows.Add("sam", 1);
    table1.Rows.Add("mark", 2);

    // Create a DataSet and put both tables in it.
    DataSet ds= new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(table1);


gridMerit.DataSource=ds;
gridMerit.DatBind();
```

Comment: `gridMerit.DataBind();` is right, not `gridMerit.DatBind();`